# SpringBoot MongoDB inherited CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate becoming null

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a base class for fields that are common in all the models

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class BaseModel {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdAt;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedAt;
    @Version
    private Long version;
}
```

and other models are inheriting this class, for eg

```
@Document(collection = "accounts")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Account extends BaseModel {
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

When I persist account object then i can see createdAt and modifiedAt getting persisted, but when i query the same account object then I am getting createdAt and modifiedAt as null.
I have enabled mongo auditing also.
I have tried TypeAlias also but not working, any suggestion or help would be appreciated

Comment: Try to use "java.time.Instant' instead of Date.

Comment: tried it, but not working

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm struggling with it right now.